# Selenium 2.35 WebDriver Quit Fails with IE 10

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I open a page and at the end of the test attempt to close it by calling my CelanUp() in a finally block but sometimes IEDriverServer and the browser are left open. There are no open popups when this happens.

```
    public void CelanUp ()
    {
        string dialogResponse = string.Empty;

        if (m_Driver != null)
        {
            //Dismiss all dialogs:
            dialogResponse = CloseLogonDialog();
            dialogResponse = CloseConfirmDialog();

            m_Driver.Quit();
            m_Driver = null;
        }

        if (dialogResponse != string.Empty)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(dialogResponse);
        }
    }
```

What else can I do the close the browser and IEDriverServer?

Edit:

because Selenium's Quit is letting me down by leaving windows open i have looked at other solutions:

```
try
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("IEDriverServer.exe"))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What are you using? NUnit? When you call .Quit does the call get executed fine but the process is still left running? Is this using the 64bit version of the driver or 32bit? How are the tests run? Via NUnit's GUI? Some automated script? CI? Does it always do this no matter how it is run?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I am using an in-house test harness. Quit is called fine and the process is still left open. I am using the 64bit driver, v2.35.3.0. In 20 runs .Quit did not close the process but the .Kill did 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what unit testing software you're using, instead of doing the logic like this, i'd recommend delegating the browser to the unit testing framework.

Put the cleanup method in an `After` method.  as in, `After each test... do this`.

In java, using jUnit, it'd be written like this.

```
@After
public void cleanUp() {
  driver.quit();
}
```

This means, `after each test, call driver.quit()`

Comment: The cleanUp is called at the end of test session. What do you think of my edit?

Comment: your edit is _hideous!_  haha.. let the testing framework handle it.